# Methods of manipulating/controling Windows Save As/Open File dialogs?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I'm attempting to build a Windows program that would provide a folder-bookmarks-ish functionality, that would allow you to hit a hotkey and navigate the dialog you have open to the folder assigned. Of course, to do this I'd need to be able to manipulate Windows Explorer dialogs and such. Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do a bit more? It doesn't sound like you're talking about manipulating the SaveAs/OpenFile dialogs in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a reference to SHDocVw Described Here: [StackOverflow SHDocVw Example:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285799/how-to-connect-to-an-open-window-of-internet-explorer-using-c)

This will allow you to enumerate all of the open iexplore windows. (including the open Windows Explorer Dialogs; only issue is for certain special folders the full path is not displayed, but this can be remedied with a little creative code) You can then look through all of the open windows for URLs that have File:/// at the beginning, and then you can prompt the user to assign a hotkey for that specific open window.  I've found that the SHDocVw does not reliably return all iexplore windows all the time, so this may not be the exact solution you are looking for. It would be easier to have the user type in the path of the Folder into a textbox on the Form, and then click a button that dynamically created a global hotkey and an event handler for the global hotkey keyboard hook.  I attempted this a few different ways, and I ended up using a .cs file on codeproject Here: [CodeProject: Low Level Global Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook)

Within the event Handler for the Global Keyboard Hook, you will have to use Process.Start(x.Process), where x is of a custom class type that has the specific hotkey associated with a specific Folders Location. That way you can look at the key that was pressed in the event handler, and start the associated Process (or in this case, open the specific folder)  Each time the user adds an additional folder's location, a new object of custom type is created which includes the hotkey parameter and the folders Path (a user generated value).  This custom object type (defined below) is then added to a global list of type "folderLocation" such that it can be accessed later when keys are actually pressed. The application added each folderLocation object to the flList as they were created.

I also defined a List of type Keys and then defined the first 12 objects in this list as F1...F12.  For each folderlocation that is added, the next Key in the pre-defined list is added as the hotkey. (although you could also have the user define the hotkey)

In the end, the user presses F1, and the result is that the global key press event handler fires, and then the handler looks to see what button was pressed, compares it to the existing List of custom Types: folderLocation, and looks for a matching Key. Once Found, it then starts the associated folderLocation path using Process.Start.... Good Luck...

```
    public class folderLocation
    {
        public string folderPath { get; set; }
        public string folderName { get; set; }
        public Keys hotKey { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you will need to use pinvoke and get into the nitty gritty but it can be done.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy

Comment: I meant those owned by other applications. :/

Comment: Please don't provide the crucial details to your question in comments to answers. Please edit the question to make it clear.